# Game Score Compiling Issues on Xcode

Tags: xcode, scoring

I'm having issues compiling the score for a boxing game.

Every time the main character knocks down its opponent, the **score resets to 0** and I want the **score to be cumulative until the boxing match ends**.

Here's the logic:

**-KO: 2 knockdowns, match ends**

**-TKO: 3 knockdowns, match ends**

Any ideas to fix this?

Here's the code I am using:

```
-(void) setScore:(NSInteger)setscore withResetToZero:(BOOL) isReset {
    if (isReset) {
        score = setscore;
    }else {
        score =score + setscore;
    }
    DebugLog(@"Score is :%d",score );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the meaning of the `isReset` parameter? When is this function called?

Comment: This function is called every time the main character knocks down its opponent. The score resets to **0** after a knock down.